# Razor output html as string

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor

I wonder why my razor page output my html/css as string ? Example, the output in the browser is 
    1200 [span style=color:red]*[/span]

It suppose to be

1,200.00 *

My code in my vbhtml razor page is below

```
            result = 1,200 & "[span style=color:red]*[/span]"
```

I purposely use [] here instead of <> because if I use <> , my code is translated as html automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see the difference between two outputs.

Comment: sorry, i realize it after i posted it. anyway, i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Better you should make css class and apply as css attribute.

Comment: The thing is I have a if statement here. If hour is less than 200, then display 1,200 * else only display 1,200. I want to make this * red color.

Comment: y dont u make your * as label add its css class. and simple hide and show as per your condition.

Answer (score 0):

As in previous comment, you should use inline style.

```html
if(hour<200)
{
<div>1200<span style=color:red;>*</span></div>
}
else{
<div>1200</div>
}
```

Comment: Actually, i simplify my code too much. This print screen code is what I am havin - http://www.eduvolink.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1.jpg